# error in stored procedure ...into keyword

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Two tables Borrower(rollno,name,bookissue_date) and Fine(rollno,name,amount)

```
delimiter //
create procedure student( in roll_no int,in Nameofbook varchar(40))

begin 
    declare Dateofiss1 date;
    Declare cur cursor for 

    select Dateofiss from Borrower where Roll_no = roll into Dateofiss1;

    OPEN cur;
    fetch cur into Dateofiss1
    if(datediff(sysdate(),Dateofiss1)<15) then varchar(20))
        update Borrower set status='R'where Roll_no=roll_no

    elseif(datediff(sysdate(),Dateofiss1)>=15)and datediff (sysdate(),Dateofiss1<30)
        SET FINEAMOUNT=5*(datediff(sysdate(),Dateofiss1)-15)
        insert into Fine(Roll_no,Date,amount)values(rollno,sysdate,fineamount);
        update.borrower set status='R' where Roll_no='rollno';
    elseif (datediff(sysdate(),Dateofiss1)>30)
        SET FINEAMOUNT=50*(datediff(sysdate(),Dateofiss1)-15)
        insert into Fine(Roll_no,Date,amount)values(rollno,sysdate,fineamount);
        update.borrower set status='R' where Roll_no='rollno';

        close cur;
    end if
    select * from Borrower;
    elect * from Fine;
end
```

Comment: What is `then varchar(20))` supposed to mean? And you have an extra `)` that doesn't match anything.

Comment: You're missing `THEN` after each of the `ELSEIF` statements.

Comment: `update.borrower` should be `update borrower`.

Comment: This seems to be a cursor that only ever has one record - I suspect you don't need a cursor at all can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of syntax errors.

1. You have an extraneous `varchar(20))` in the first `if` statement.
2. You're missing `THEN` in the `ELSEIF` statements.
3. You wrote `update.borrower` instead of `update borrower`.
4. You have `roll_no` in quotes in some of your `update` statements.
5. The `roll_no` parameter is the same as a table column, since column names are case-insensitive. The condition `where Roll_no = roll_no` will match every row because of this. Give the parameter a different name.
6. In a `SELECT`, the `INTO` clause goes after `FROM`, not at the end.
7. There's no need to use a cursor if you're using `SELECT INTO`. Just execute the query and it will set the variable.

You can also simplify the code by putting the date difference in a variable, so you don't have to repeatedly calculate it. And in the `ELSEIF` you don't need to test `>= 15`, since you'll only get there if the `< 15` test failed.

The `UPDATE` statement is the same in all conditions, so it doesn't need to be in the `IF` at all.

```
delimiter //
create procedure student( in p_roll_no int,in Nameofbook varchar(40))

begin 
    declare Dateofiss1 date;
    declare diff INT;

    select Dateofiss from Borrower into Dateofiss1 where Roll_no = p_roll_no;

    OPEN cur;
    SET diff = datediff(sysdate(),Dateofiss1)

    IF diff BETWEEN 15 AND 29 THEN
        SET FINEAMOUNT= 5 * (diff - 15)
        insert into Fine(Roll_no,Date,amount)values(rollno,sysdate,fineamount);
    else
        SET FINEAMOUNT= 50 * (diff - 15)
        insert into Fine(Roll_no,Date,amount)values(rollno,sysdate,fineamount);    
    end if
    update Borrower set status='R'where Roll_no=p_roll_no
    select * from Borrower;
    select * from Fine;
end
```

Comment: and select Dateofiss from Borrower , dateoffiss doesn't appear int the table definition  Borrower(rollno,name,bookissue_date)